# How does pointer semantic method provide data?

Tags: go

For the below data:

```
var productList = []*Product{
    &Product{
        ID:          1,
        Name:        "Latte",

    }, &Product{
        ID:          2,
        Name:        "Espresso",
    },
}
```

---

if a method(`ToJSON`) is written with pointer semantics, as shown below:

```
package data

type Products []*Product

func (p *Products) ToJSON(w io.Writer) error {
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
    return encoder.Encode(p)
}

func GetProducts() Products {
    return productList
}
```

---

With pointer semantics, we are not creating a copy of data. After invoking below code:

```
productList := data.GetProducts()
productList.TOJSON()
```

How `encoder.Encode(p)` different from `encoder.Encode(*p)` in a method with pointer semantics?

Comment: The method's semantics are irrelevant, what matters is the value you're passing.

Answer (score 2):

`Encode` gets an `interface{}` argument, so if you pass `*p`, a copy of `p` will be passed, if you pass `p`, a copy of the pointer to `p` will be passed. `Encode` descends the tree using reflection while automatically dereferencing pointers, so nothing really matters for this case.

Comment: one more query, If there is no type definition(`type Products []*Product`), then how to write the receiver semantics syntax as pointer semantics? `(p *[]*Product)` doesn't work.

Comment: [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receiver) says: "Its type must be a defined type `T` or a pointer to a defined type `T`. `T` is called the receiver base type. A receiver base type cannot be a pointer or interface type "

Comment: With respect to your answer: In  this case, `Encode` is actually deferencing pointer. But in general, passing `*p` is different from `p`

Comment: As I said: if you pass `p` to an interface, you'll pass a copy of it. In general that is different. Encode does not care. Re: pointers: The method `func (*Products) ToJSON(io.Writer)` is equivalent to `func ToJSON(*Products,io.Writer)` except the type semantics.

Comment: Shall I raise separate query on receiver semantics? mentioned above

Comment: @overexchange, re: mentioned above: lots of things are mentioned above. Are you talking about the spec comment? That simply says you cannot define a method for an interface type, or for a type whose base type is a pointer. If that is not clear, please ask a separate question.